# When my computer says my password is weak, and suggest a new one, is that password safe?

Tags: passwords

I was logging into YouTube when Apple said my password was weak, and I should change it. Is this randomly generated password safe?

Comment: From a layman's perspective, yes, it is safe. From a very technical perspective it is still safe, but does introduce some different, tiny risks that are *very* esoteric, e.g. if Apple's code base were compromised (although if that happened they would just log your keystrokes), or if someone figured out how to use patterns in its random number generator to narrow the the search space. Both of these are so unlikely that I wouldn't think about them.

Comment: Safe in what way? It's harder to brute force that password, or "decrypt" hash of that password (if someone get database of users information)

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

Humans are terrible at passwords, and that is backed by the fact that every domain password dump I've attempted to crack contains passwords like `Rome1993` or `October2022` or `Julia01!`.

If your browser informs you that your password is weak, then that's a sign that you should change it as soon as possible.

As you can see from the examples posted, these passwords are usually trivial to crack, as they all follow the "Word+Number(+Symbol)" structure. A randomly generated password will not have any such structure, and it will also be long enough.

A password like `2AF8^(Qp.]BN~Xked,Jsi\cO` will be effectively impossible to crack. And since your browser will store it for you, you don't risk forgetting it either.

Comment: [Usually](https://www.zdnet.com/article/kaspersky-password-manager-caught-out-making-easily-bruteforced-passwords/ "Kaspersky Password Manager caught out making easily bruteforced passwords") ☹️

Comment: @AdamKatz Damn. That's what today's youth would refer to as a "bruh moment".